# How do I make 3 images which span across the width of the site responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

So I would like to have 3 images along the full width of the website, each of them acting as 1/3. I would like them to be responsive and scale accordingly on different screen sizes and have them maintain aspect ratio, any ideas how I would go about that?

So far I have managed this, however they shrink very unnaturally when the site is scaled down.

[image: SS]

Here's the code for it so far:

```css
#content {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.images {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img src="images/phantom.png" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Phantom of the Opera">
  <img src="images/lion_king.png" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Lion King">
  <img src="images/wicked.png" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Wicked">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were almost there,wrap the images in a `div` then set those divs `flex-basis` one third, you can do that by using `calc()` and set `(max-)width:100%` to `img`s

EDIT - OP's comments

> This works, however the heights of the image are messed up and all different heights, not flush with the footer. How would I fix the
>   heights too

Because you have images with different ratio sizes, you have to add `display:flex` to `div`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#content {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#content>div {
  flex: 0 calc(100%/3);
  display: flex;
  /*demo*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x800" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Phantom of the Opera"> </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x800" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Lion King">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x800" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Wicked"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, however the heights of the image are messed up and all different heights, not flush with the footer. How would I fix the heights too?

Comment: wanna show me an example of what you have and what you want with your current images

Comment: Sure, basically I have the original sizes of the images to not reduce quality, and so the heights are slightly different. I uploaded the site onto github pages to show you what's happening:
 
https://pinkiebarto.github.io/LondonWestEnd/


I'm looking for it to be flushed to the footer like so:

http://i.imgur.com/QGuKOAM.png

Comment: for that remove `flex: 0 calc(100%/3)`

Comment: That does fix the issue, but now the first image is wider than the other two so the images are no longer 1/3s

Comment: @PinkieBarto sorry for late reply, see updated answer. basically, where you have `flex: 0 calc(100%/3)` add `display:flex`, with these two you can achieve what you want

Comment: That works, but now through doing this the aspect ratio of images are all messed up and stretched.. I was thinking of integrating `object-fit: cover;` into this somehow to preserve the aspect ratio. Any ideas?

Comment: up to you, it [won't work in IE/EDGE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

Comment: That shouldn't really be an issue, since this site is for my school assignment and isn't actually going to go live.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a container element and set the images to `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%`.

```css
#content {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

.images {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Phantom of the Opera">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Lion King">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="images" alt="Image of an actor from the musical Wicked">
  </div>
</div>
```